# After Migration, Warning: include_once() errors on all pages

Tags: cache, include

We migrated our site to a new host and changed the domain name, and now all pages are displaying errors:

> Warning: include_once(includes/class-wc-download-handler.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/34/11939834/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 258
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/class-wc-download-handler.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/34/11939834/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 258
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/34/11939834/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php:258) in /home/content/34/11939834/html/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/ninja-forms.php on line 294

We are also unable to login at wp-login.php

Our site url is *www.dv8sports.com*

Any suggestions to what the problem might be?

**UPDATE 8/6/14**
The files in question were *uploaded* to the GoDaddy server, but they were *deleted* by GoDaddy without a Failed Upload notification. Here is what comes up in FileZilla

```
Command:    STOR class-wc-download-handler.php
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   226-File successfully transferred
Response:   226-0.312 seconds (measured here), 156.34 Kbytes per second
Response:   226 *** MALWARE DETECTED ***
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 51,704 bytes in 1 second
```

Comment: the download handler module of wc

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect some additional information I found, I'd like to post the answer to it (since i fixed and I think others using GoDaddy hosting might have this same problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered some useful resources about GoDaddy hosting and its malware screening:

The files in question were *uploaded* to the GoDaddy server, but they were *deleted* by GoDaddy without a Failed Upload notification. Here is what comes up in FileZilla

```
Command:    STOR class-wc-download-handler.php
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   226-File successfully transferred
Response:   226-0.312 seconds (measured here), 156.34 Kbytes per second
Response:   226 *** MALWARE DETECTED ***
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 51,704 bytes in 1 second
```

So when we were uploading a full WordPress site (over 10k files) we didn't see that about 1% of our files were marked as malware and deleted.

This post describes GoDaddy's unreliable malware handling, which lead me to my solution.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2228539

The best solution was to identify the files that were not uploaded and upload them one-by-one in GoDaddy Hosting File Manager. This was very time consuming. Will not work for clients again who are using GoDaddy for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue when migrating from one host to another. You have those errors because path to include file is not correct (path do not exist on new host). Maybe you used absolute paths to files on old host, now, on new host path is different and that is why you have those errors . OR, those files are not moved correctly from old host to new host.

What you should do is next:

Firstly, check if mentioned file(s) exist on new host (for example this file "includes/class-wc-download-handler.php"), if not, transfer it from old host again to be sure.

If file are there, and it is correct size, than open "/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php" go to line 258, or search for "class-wc-download-handler.php" check and correct if needed path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; the issue was much deeper than that. I will post a completed answer in a moment.

Comment: I will look at your update.

Comment: Your file(s) are detected as malware and deleted by server script. Now, open your file(s) and look for some external .js files, or remote include files (search for include, or include_once, require, require_once functions inside that file and look if there is some strange file, and delete it, or comment out. Than try to upload again. Also you can contact you host and send them that file to be cleaned by them.

Comment: all the files that had an external link of any kind (www.mit.edu in the license, woo-themes.com in some of the plugins) were flagged and deleted. In the end, we uploaded all of the missing files one-by-one in the file manager, which has no malware screening.

Comment: I hope my answers were useful?

Answer (score -1):

You might have tried to use their file manager with Google Chrome, as it allows you to upload folders as well as files using a drag and drop method.

Comment: That is not even remotely related to the question